# Python on Windows - change local timezone

Tags: windows, python-3.x, timezone

I am newbie to python and was googling for ages although never found an answer to my question - may be you could help me directing

I am working on automating of one application deployment which has the part of changing the local server timezone (windows is the platform). Moreover, I am using the Listbox from tkinter to gather the input of the required timezone from user (listbox is filled with common_timezones from pytz).

I wanted to change it with a python, using pytz and transferring the result to tzutils but never succeeded, as the result of pytz is in Unix format and tzutils accepts 'UTC+'.

Is there any native fuction in python which could help me in changing the timezone locally or may be way to convert result of pytz to the input format which will be accepted by tzutils? Or I am going some wrong way?

Comment: Your question is confusing.

Comment: sorry for this, actually, if I knew how to explain this more precise I never asked this. Sorry again.

Comment: Why would you need to change the timezone? Typically you'd want UTC times internally and only use the user's configured timezone for display purposes.

Comment: It is application limitation which depends on a server timezone

Comment: Relying on the server time zone is a bad idea.  It's a system-wide setting.  You could have two applications fighting for it to be two different things.  This is a known antipattern - avoid it at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the time zone try this:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
print strftime("%z", gmtime())
```

Comment: Thanks. Though am I right that there is no way of getting any timezone different from the one which is already set up on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, I used powershell call from python script for this. thank you.